# How to specify scaling properties in an Azure ServiceConfiguration

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

The documentation specifies how to set a role to have more than one instance, as so:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="...">
  <Role name="MyRoleName">
    <Instances count="3"/>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

However, the new Azure has a bunch more properites in the portal, like scaling by a metric (queue), instance range, and queue name. How would one specifiy these values in the ServiceConfiguration file? I cannot find documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you can't. From what I understand, Autoscaling is a separate service (or component) which sits outside of your cloud service. There's a separate API for configuring this <del>but to the best of my knowledge that has not been made public yet</del>, information about which can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510374.aspx. (Hat tip to @kwill for providing this information).

Comment: FYI, the Autoscaling API is available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510374.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling values are not provided in the service configuration.  You can only define them thru a portal or an API.  They live outside of your deployment.